# What is the chain of custody of a mail-in election ballot?

Tags: election, ballot

What happens to my ballot after I mail it? Who opens the envelope? Who tallies my vote? What anti-fraud measures are in place? I live in California, Santa Clara County.

Comment: Here is a somewhat informative news article from Michigan:
http://www.detroitnews.com/story/news/politics/2016/10/27/michs-elections-designer-easy-path-fraud/92869002/